# How can I use the ACL properties of Google Cloud Storage to make dynamically created files instantly available to the public?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twilio

So I'm trying to create an python based app in appengine that sends voice mails via Twilio. In order to do this Twilio needs an XML file that is publicly available.  I have a web form that my end-users use to create a message.  I then take that text and generate the XML file and put it in cloud storage which kind of looks like this:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import cloudstorage
filename = '/mydomain.appspot.com/twilio/test_message3.xml'
```

Now this part is key, Here I'm creating the file and setting the ACL to public-read as per the documentation.

```
gcs_file = cloudstorage.open(filename,'w',content_type='text/xml',options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'})
```

Here I add the content to the file.

```
xml_message = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Say voice="woman" language="en">Hello.  This is a test voice message.</Say></Response>"""
gcs_file.write(xml_message)
gcs_file.close()
```

Now to test the access permissions I've been doing the following:

1. I upload another xml file manually to the same bucket via the appengine console.
2. I then open an icognito window in chrome to pretend to be an anonymous user and I try to access both files.
3. I then try to access both files using the standard google cloud storage uri: http://storage.googleapis.com/mydomain.appspot.com/twilio/test_message3.xml

and

http://storage.googleapis.com/mydomain.appspot.com/twilio/manually_loaded_message.xml

When I try to view the file I uploaded manually I get an Access Denied Error and when I access the file I created dynamically I can access the file with no problems.  Now on the surface this appears to have worked exactly the way I want, but apparently appengine is fooling me.  When I try to make the API call to Twilio using the file I created dynamically I get a 403 Access Denied Error.  The call to Twilio looks like this:

```
account_sid = "MY_SID"
    auth_token  = "MY_TOKEN"
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    call = client.calls.create(url="http://storage.googleapis.com/mydomain.appspot.com/twilio/test_message3.xml",
                               to="+15551234747",
                               from_="+15554446321")
    call.sid
```

So obviously that file I created dynamically is not publicly available. Even though the documentation says it can be done https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#xgoogacl.

Does anyone have any idea why setting the ACL on file creation doesn't work?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm currently running into the same issue with GCS links not being publicly available even with `options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'}`...

Comment: Nope.  I had to create an xml file template and load the contents of the Twilio message dynamically from NDB, I then setup a public route in app.yaml to access the message.  The only other way to make the file publicly available was to use blobstore and push it to the browser via send_blob or create a public bucket and store the files there.  Cloudstorage is very frustrating.  Good luck.